# Tell me how to release password change for Django users?

Tags: django

Tell me how to create the ability to change the password using my html form? I do not want to use annual ChangePasswordForm. I’ve been suffering for 1 hour and can’t find a solution.

Comment: What do you mean with *annual* `ChangePasswordForm`? What exactly is the problem with using a form?

Comment: Oh, sory. I used google translate. I  meant "simple"